# Proving that the exponential function is bijective

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

Prove that $\exp: \mathbb{R} \mapsto (0,\infty)$ is a bijection.

Okay, so the first part is really easy: injectivity follows directly from writing the exponential function as a series.

Surjectivity... is not so easy. I have no idea how to show it directly, and I was thinking maybe I could show that

$\inf(e^x) = 0$ and $\sup(e^x) = \infty$, and that $e^x$ is continuous over all of $\mathbb{R}$. Does this imply surjectivity over $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: Yeah, by the intermediate value theorem, it does.

Comment: Hint: intermediate value property

Comment: perfect, thanks, forgot about IVT!

Comment: why does the injectivity follow from writing it as a series?

Comment: @sranthrop if I take $f(x) = f(y)$ for $x$ not equal $y$ and write it out in series expansion, clearly $(1+x)$ not equal $(1+y)$ and we can argue similarly for each individual term in the series.

Comment: @terribleatmath I am not sure that argument works--just because the individual terms are unequal does not mean the entire series is unequal.

Comment: @Goos fair enough, could you tell me a sufficient argument for injectivity here then?

Comment: @terribleatmath Go for strict monotonicity.

Comment: By the way, how do you see the injectivity from the series for negative $x$?

Comment: @terribleatmath Can you give us your definition of the exponential function?  Did you define it as a series?  Do you know that $\exp (a + b) = \exp a \exp b$?  Do you know that $\exp$ is differentiable and is its own derivative?

Comment: We do not know that exp is differentiable yet as we have not defined differentiability, however we have established all of the other properties you speak of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Injectivity**

- If you know that $\exp' = \exp$, use the fact that $\exp'(x) = \exp > 0 \;\; \forall \, x$.
- Alternatively, if you know that $\exp (a + b) = \exp a  \exp b$, then assume $\exp x = \exp y$.  Conclude $\exp(x - y) = 1$.  Assume WLOG $x \ge y$, and then use the series expansion of $\exp(x - y)$ to show $x - y = 0$, hence $x = y$.

**Surjectivity**

Fix $x \in (0, \infty)$.  Find $a$ and $b$ with $e^a < x$, $e^b > x$.
Apply Intermediate Value Theorem to the interval between $a$ and $b$.