# Show that $b^{x}$ is bijective

Tags: exponential-function, inverse-function

Show that a function defined by $f(x) = b^{x} : \mathbb R \rightarrow (0,\infty)$, where $b > 1$ is a bijective function and therefore invertable.
 The parenthesis around $0, \infty$ means that the target set is created than $0$ but less than $\infty$.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any help from you is appreciated (by votes), start by stating all that you know about the problem  in the question itself(for example, how would you start out, where you are stuck, etc.)

Comment: Fundamentally, this depends on how you define $b^x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: to show a function is bijective, you must show

1. it is one-to-one, i.e. "injective", and
2. it is onto, i.e. "surjective"

Hint 2:

- To show the function is injective start with $f(a) = f(b)$, and use
  what you know about the function $f$ to reach the conclusion that $a
     = b$. (Side note: the visual method of doing this is called the "horizontal line test.")
- To show the function is surjective, start with $f(x) = y$, and show that, no matter what $y$ is, you can always solve for $x$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know the definition, I have problems to show it.  Thanks

Comment: Ah, I see. I will provide another answer to address further, then.

Comment: And for $b \gt 1$ you can assume that $b^x$ is monotonic strict increasing on $x \gt 0$

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, I will further address an answer. Take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705653/proving-that-the-exponential-function-is-bijective). They use $e^x$ instead of $b^x$, but if you can prove that $e^x$ is invertible, you can adjust the proof for $b^x$.